# how to receive inner property string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to receive the `dependency` string from the `dataDependencyMap`.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <script>  
  var data =
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "active": true,
      "dependency": [
        {"id": 2, "type": "critical" },
        {"id": 3, "type": "moderate"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "active": true,
      "dependency":[
        {"id": 3, "type": "moderate"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "active": false,
      "dependency":[]
    }
  ]
  
  // this works as it should
  
  var dataActiveMap = new Map(data.map(obj => [obj.id, obj.active]))
  
  data.forEach(function({id}) {
    if (dataActiveMap.get(id) == true ) {
      console.log(id, "active: ", true)
    }
  })

  // HERE IS THE PROBLEM: How can I return the dependency string, like "critical" or "moderate"

  var dataDependencyMap = new Map(data.map(obj => [obj.id, obj.dependency]))
  
  data.forEach(function({id}) {
    if (dataActiveMap.get(id) == true) {
      console.log(id, "dependency: ", dependency.value)
    }
  })
  
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not clear, what do you want output to be? can add sample output

Comment: You can use the entire object as the value in `Map` like:  `data.map(obj => [obj.id, obj] )`. Then `const obj = dataActiveMap.get(id)` will return the entire object. You can check for `if (obj.active )` property and get the `obj.dependency`

Comment: Thanks @adiga, this would be also a good approach. Unfortunately I receive an ReferenceError : id is not defined. I guess it must be me.

Comment: @adiga solved it, thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no value property of *dependency*, you can pass *dependency* so that you can access that object like the following way:

```html
<script>  
  var data =
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "active": true,
      "dependency": [
        {"id": 2, "type": "critical" },
        {"id": 3, "type": "moderate"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "active": true,
      "dependency":[
        {"id": 3, "type": "moderate"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "active": false,
      "dependency":[]
    }
  ]

  // this works as it should

  var dataActiveMap = new Map(data.map(obj => [obj.id, obj.active]))

  data.forEach(function({id}) {
    if (dataActiveMap.get(id) == true ) {
      //console.log(id, "active: ", true)
    }
  })

  // HERE IS THE PROBLEM: How can I return the dependency string, like "critical" or "moderate"

  var dataDependencyMap = data.map(({id, dependency}) => ({id, dependency}));
  data.forEach(function({id, dependency}) {
    if (dataActiveMap.get(id) == true) {
      //console.log(id, "dependency: ", dependency);
      // if you need the *type* property as comma separated string
      console.log("id:", id, "and dependency:", dependency.map(({type}) => type).join(', '));
    }
  })

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the dataActiveMap constant would be used for but an alternative solution would be to use for loops. If you still need the dataActiveMap and dataDependencyMap, you can always create those arrays and use the `push()` method to add the values to the arrays at appropriate times in the loops. Check the solution below.

```
for (key in data){ // loops through the data array
  
    // console.log(data[key]) 

    if (data[key].active) // checks if each object's active property in data array  is true
    {
      // console.log(data[key].dependency)

      for (dependency in data[key].dependency) // loops through dependencies
      {
        // console.log(data[key].dependency[dependency])

        for (props in data[key].dependency[dependency]) // loops through objects nested in dependencies
        {
          console.log(data[key].dependency[dependency].type) //prints the type property
        }
      }
    }
  }
```